# Looking for a manhwa about reincarnation and travel back in time wherein the female lead was killed before

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about a woman that is being reincarnated or time traveled back in time. She was killed. He was about to have a husband who is busy fighting off monsters. I think her husband is a soldier who went out to fight monsters. He came back to the castle where he left her?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a little like Leveling My Husband to the Max, but I'm not sure it's a little vague. It also reminds me of Under the oak tree but she doesn't die.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by focusing on just one possible answer and explaining how it does, and equally importantly how it _does not_ match the question.  (It's possible that the OP has confused things, so the answer should be clear about the elements of the story.)

Answer (score 0):

As per P.A.'s answer, *[Leveling My Husband to the Max](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/leveling-up-my-husband-to-the-max/)* is a match for the details you have provided. At the beginning of the manhwa, she and her husband, Carlyx Talessdo, are to be executed due to having been framed for Treason against the Emperor. She spent ten years of her marriage with Carlyx largely staying away from home, fighting monsters, and her being belittled by the staff and her mother-in-law due to Carlyx not treating her as an equal and the marriage not being consummated for several years. After her death, she awakes on the first day of her marriage, and convinces Carlyx to both not immediately leave to fight the monsters but also to address her as an equal.